# ¿Por qué tengo que usar webpack en Vue.js cuando uso componentes?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Entiendo que Webpack se utiliza para compilar, minificar o transpilar código para que quede JS que pueda entender el navegador; sin embargo, si utilizo HTML y Vue.js como un scrip agregado, puedo utilizar la mayor parte de Vue.js; sin embargo, he notado que cuando hay que utilizar componentes, el uso de Webpack es casi obligado.

No entiendo mucho realmente porqué es tan importante, y porqué si cargo la librería de otra manera no puedo utilizarlo sin webpack.

Comment: Webpack no es necesario en vue ni para hacer componentes

Comment: puso casi obligado. la mayoria de las documentaciones dicen como compilar algo junto con webpack, porque es el standard. Sin embargo, sin eso se puede generar lo mismo, lo que pasa es que no va a estar ni transpilado, ni minificado, ni nada. pero deberian poder utilizarse sin problemas.

Comment: Tienes razón @gbianchi

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente esos componentes que intentas agregar utilizan **ECMAScript 6** o **typescript** o similares y por eso deben ser compilados antes de poder utilizarlos para el navegador, de ahí que sea necesario webpack